Why range(n) doesn't include numerical value 0?
def get_chess_square_color(column, row):
    if not (column and row in range(9)):
        return ''
    elif column == row:  
        return 'white'
    else:
        return 'black'

assert get_chess_square_color(0, 8) == ''

After writing this function, I notice this code line  assert get_chess_square_color(0, 8) == ''
I really don't understand, normally 0 is a part ofrange(9), so I expected get_chess_square_color(0, 8) to return 'white',
Does in this case, range elements don't correspond to their numerical value but instead represent an indexing ?, like
text = 'Look'
print(text[0])

will OUTPUT 'L', 1st character of text indexed by the number 0

Surely you mean column in range(9) and row in range(9)?

This doesn't do what you think it does:  column and row in range(9)  Hint:  It parses as column and (row in range(9)).  So it will always be false if column is false, i.e. when column is 0.  That's the sort of mistake that happens when you try to invent your own syntax.

This is not a typo. SO what is happening? This is something the OP doesn’t understand and should be helped with.

The linked duplicates are not exact but they point out the root issue. The exact case is covered by existing answers and comments here.

@AndrasDeak--СлаваУкраїні so why close to begin with? If the linked duplicates are not exact?

@ChukwujiobiCanon because the core issue is a duplicate, it's been answered dozens or maybe hundreds of times, and it's the kind of question that is unlikely to help future readers (think if someone with the same problem will find this question). This probably also explains any "typo" votes. We really don't want any more answers here, closing is appropriate.

The condition if not (column and row in range(9)): is not checking if column is in range(9). It’s only checking if row is in range(9) and whether column is non-zero.
What you're trying to write should look like this statement
if column not in range(9) or row not in range(9):

Your statement:
if not (column and row in range(9)):

is equivalent to:
if not ((column) and (row in range(9))):

The column by itself evaluates as false when it's 0, true if it's any other number.

To test that multiple values are members of a sequence, you cannot do this by chaining multiple ands together to test that. That is why your approach doesn’t work.
You can however use sets to do this test for membership. Construct a set from the sequence, then also construct a set from the values to test for.
Example:
a, b = 17043, 5367709
{a, b} <= set(range(10000000)) # <— Returns True because a and b are members of the range range(10000000).
a, b = "frog", "toad"
{a, b} <= set(•••A very long sequence of amphibians read from file•••)
This scales and I thought I should put this here for posterity. But your case is very simple:
if not {column, row} <= range(9)):
Now the two values column and row are tested for membership in the range range(9).
